# Can we set Invocable Variables through a test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, invocable-method

I want to write a test class to test an Invocable Method. Is it possible to do this without using the Process Builder to initialize my Invocable Variables? The code for the class I want to test is pasted below.

```
global class DSSendtoQueue {

@InvocableMethod
public static void DSSendtoQueue(List<sobjectsListRequests> requests)
{   
    System.debug('In Invocable Method');
    ID OBID;
    ID UID;
    String phoneNum;
    Datetime callBackTime;

    for (sobjectsListRequests request : requests)
    {
        OBID = request.OBID;
        UID = request.UID;
        phoneNum = '1234657890'; //request.phoneNum;
        callBackTime = request.callBackTime;
        system.debug('Time = ' + callBackTime);
    }


            try
            {
                DSSendtoBackend RTPQ = new DSSendtoBackend(UID, OBID, phoneNum, callBackTime/*priorityScore, groupNumber*/);
                ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(RTPQ);
            }
            catch(exception e)
            {
                System.debug('Failed to enqueue batch job.  Error: ' + e);
            }            
}

global class sobjectsListRequests
{
    @InvocableVariable(required=True)
    public Id OBID;
    @InvocableVariable(required=True)
    public Id UID;
    @InvocableVariable(required=False)
    public String phoneNum;
    @InvocableVariable(required=False)
    public Datetime callBackTime;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - the `@Invocable...` annotations provide extra data to the Process Builder. The code is still a normal Apex class whose methods you can call and fields you can set from a test class or any other Apex code.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I can't believe I thought I couldn't do that for some reason. Thanks!